# cats() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'

Tags: python, django

I'm a amature django web developer. I have a problam with Django. this error is "cats() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'".
please see my codes and help me.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/1
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
cats() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 112
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Post (models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    body = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    tags = TaggableManager ()
    cats = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blog.models import Post, Category

urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(
        queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:2],
        template_name="index.html")),       
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', 'cats', name='cats'),

)
```

**views.py**

```
from blog.models import Post,Category
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def cats(request):
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")
    navitem = Category.objects.all().order_by("title")
    return render_to_response('post.html',{'queryset':queryset,'navitem':navitem},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line in **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', 'cats', name='cats')
```

You are sending to the view an argument that it doesn't need.

You can include the `pk` argument in the view parameters, like this:

```
def cats(request, pk):
```

or this:

```
def cats(request, pk=None):
```

Or, even better, you can use a different pattern in your URL, without [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) it (because you are not using that `pk` value at all in your view, you don't need to create a variable for it), like this:

```
url(r'^(\d+)$', 'cats', name='cats')
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much dear. why I can't see my category in my site? I use {{navitem.title}} for this purpose But unfortunately I Can't see any item in the page. when I use {{navitem}} I see "[<Category: item1 >]" for example.

Comment: You are probably missing the [`__unicode__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode) function in your model.

Comment: I'm sorry But it's any mistake :( please see my models.py. There is __unicode__ Function in my model.